# How to query with analyzers and stop-words in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

So what I need to do is to pass some information from XML files into elasticsearch and then search those files with tfidf weights applied to them. I also need to output the top 20 best results. I want to do this with python.

So far I have been able to pass the XML data and create an index successfully through python by creating arrays and then indexing them through a json-like format. I am aware that this means that while indexing most other options that are available through elasticsearch get a default value however I was unable to find a way to do this in a different way. What remains for me to do since all the data is passed into the index, is to search for it. I am given 10 documents that contain the title and a small summary of the text contained and I need to return the top 20 results with tfidf through elasticsearch.  This is how I gather the 10 text files that need to be searched for in my index and this is how I try to search for them.

```
queries = []
with open("testingQueries.txt") as file:
    queries = [i.strip() for i in file]


for query_text in queries:
    query = {
        'query': {
            'more_like_this': {
                'fields': ['document.text'],
                'like': query_text
            }
        }
    }
    results = es.search(index=INDEX_NAME, body=query)
    print(str(results) + "\n")
```

As you can see I haven't added an analyzer in this query and I have no idea how to add tfidf weights to search for these queries in my data. I've been searching for an answer everywhere but most answers are either not python related or do not really solve my problem. The search results that I am getting are also not giving me the top 20 results...in fact they aren't giving me any results. The output looks like this: {'took': 14, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': 0, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}

when I try to do the same with 'match' instead of 'more_like_this' I get a lot more results with hits but again I would still need tfidf scores and a result of the top 20 documents that are similar to my queries.